# display paragraph based on conditions

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, pdf, rendering

I have a VFP and I'd like to show some of my paragraph based on conditions.

Here is one example of my code:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!Offer__c.Offer_Type__c == 'Conditional' && Offer__.Degree__c != 'Master'}">
        <p style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;">Paragraph will be display</p>
        </apex:outputText>
```

For example above code I'd like to display one paragraph based on Offer type is conditional and degree is not master. offer type and degree fields are picklist fiedls. When I try use above code paragraph is still showing even if my record degree is master.

How can I fix it? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: You have a typo, `Offer__.Degree__c` is missing `c'.

Answer (score 0):

Your `rendered` attribute has a mistake:

```
{!Offer__c.Offer_Type__c == 'Conditional' && Offer__.Degree__c != 'Master'}
```

when you check on Degree, you use `Offer__.`(see the missing character after the double underscores). Also, I think it should be `Offer__r` instead of `Offer__c`, but not 100% sure